# Fazer leitura de 2 ou mais arquivos csv

Tags: php, csv

Criei um script onde o usuário irá enviar um ou mais arquivo CSV, ele irá enviar e então o php deve pegar o nome desse arquivo e fazer algumas mudanças(requisito do sistema)e salvar no banco de dados e apagar esse arquivo, **o problema é o seguinte com 1 arquivo ele converte tranquilamente com 2 ou mais arquivos ele não funciona mais**

HTML

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Arquivo CSV</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <center><h1>Exportar Excel</h1></center>
        <form method="post" name="frm_csv" action="ler_csv.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
            <center><fieldset style="width:50px">
                <legend>Script CSV</legend>
                <label for="arquivo">Arquivo CSV: 
                    <input id="file_csv" name="file_csv[]" type="file"  required><br><br>

                </label>
                <label for "ano">Ano:    
                    <input id="ano" name="ano" type="text" size="4" required><br><br>
                </label>
                <label for "ano">Semestre:    
                    <input id="semestre" name="semestre" type="text" size="1" required><br><br>
                </label>

                <button type="submit">OK</button>
            </fieldset></center>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?
require_once 'conecta_pg.inc';
require_once 'includes.inc';

$ano=$_REQUEST['ano'];
$semestre=$_REQUEST['semestre'];

$arquivo = isset($_FILES["file_csv"]) ? $_FILES["file_csv"] : FALSE;

foreach($arquivo as $arquivo){
$arquivo_nome_disciplina = $arquivo["name"];
preg_match("/\.(csv){1}$/i", $arquivo["name"], $ext);


$arquivo_nome = date("d-m-Y_H-i-s") . "." . $ext[1];
move_uploaded_file($arquivo["tmp_name"], $arquivo_nome);

$row = 0;
$handle = fopen ($arquivo_nome,"r");


$nome_disciplina = explode("_", $arquivo_nome_disciplina);
//echo $nome_disciplina[0];
//echo str_replace(".csv","",$nome_disciplina[1]);
$nome_disciplina[1]=str_replace(".csv","",$nome_disciplina[1]);


$db = conecta_banco();
$comando="insert into avaliacao.disciplina(nome,codigo) values('".$nome_disciplina[1]."','".$nome_disciplina[0]."')";
$sql= pg_query($db,$comando);



while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ";")) {
   $num = count ($data);
   $row++;

   $coluna1 = $data[0];


   if($coluna1!='RA'){

        $aluno = localiza_aluno_ra($coluna1);
        //echo "RA:".$coluna1."RA da Tabela".$aluno['ra']; //CONFERE SE ESTÁ TRAZENDO OS RA CORRETOS
        $disciplina = localiza_disciplina($nome_disciplina[1]);
        //echo "Nome Disciplina: ".$nome_disciplina[0]."Nome Disciplina Tabela:".$disciplina['codigo']; //CONFERE SE ESTÁ TRAZENDO AS DISCIPLINAS CORRETAMENTE


            if($aluno['id']){   
              if($disciplina['id']){
                $db = conecta_banco();
                $comando2="insert into avaliacao.aluno_disciplina(id_aluno,id_disciplina,ano,semestre) values (".$aluno['id'].",".$disciplina['id'].",".$ano.",".$semestre.")";
                $sql=pg_query($db,$comando2) or die ("<center><font size=20>Registro já foi inserido</font><center>");
              }     
            }   

    }
}
fclose ($handle);

unlink($arquivo_nome);
}
if($sql){
    echo "<center><font size=20>Arquivo salvo</font><center>";
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=index.php" />';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro? ou acontece timeout da requisição?

Comment: `foreach($arquivo as $arquivo)` fica complicado. Use 2 nomes diferentes nas variáveis do `foreach`.

Comment: Continua dando erro mesmo após mudar o foreach  Warning: fopen(28-11-2014_09-04-52.): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in